# Why can't I read whole file?

Tags: file-io, verilog

I'm trying to do some image processing with FPGA and my supporter want us to show some simulation result with Modelsim.

So, basically we try to read image file in testbench and write it to another file but it stop read file at half of the file. Here is my source code

```
module fileio1;
  integer in,out,r;
  reg [31:0]temp;
  reg clk;
  initial
  begin
    r=0;
    temp =0;
    clk = 0;
    in = $fopen("test120.bmp","r");
    out = $fopen("result.bmp","w");
  end

  always #1 clk = ~clk;

  always @(negedge clk)
  begin
    r = $fscanf(in,"%c",temp);
  end

  always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    if(~r) $fwrite(out,"%c",temp);
  end
endmodule
```

This is that source code and our input file is 120x180 size bitmapfile (64kb)
but output file is 38kb. Almost half of file. I try it with 480x720 size bitmapfile(1013kb), it's ouput file is almost half of the origin file too.
With very small size file input, we can get the right outputfile.

Why is this happen? Is there some better function to input/output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `$fscanf` in that situation. `$fscanf` skips over white-space, including blank lines (just like `fscanf()` function in C).

You should rather use `$fread` function:

```
always @(negedge clk)
  begin
    r = $fread(temp,in);
  end
```

Comment: thank you!!

there is an error so i don't use fread first.... but it solve the problem//

fread(temp,in) is correct, so it has an error